# Jekyll: File to import not found or unreadable?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I'm developing a website using Jekyll and the sass imports aren't working correctly, I have tried changing the default _sass directory and changed the names of the files but nothing seems to work?

Any help appreciated!!

My files are as follows:

```
config.yml
    sass:
      sass_dir:assets\css


assets\css\3-sections\_-sections-dir
```

In my all.sass file

```
@import"3-sections\_-sections-dir"
```

Comment: You have \_- as a name, is this actually true? Maybe you rename and remove \_. Also, after the import statement should be a blank (reads: import"3-sections")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem, I had the 6 dashes at the start of my '_-sections-dir' file, which I removed and it worked.